# Java Bean Composite injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot, javabeans

I have an interface

```
public interface Abstraction { 
    void execute();
}
```

I have built a composite implementation and want to registered this object as the bean, `@Named`

```
@Named
public class Composite implements Abstraction {
    private List<Abstraction> list;

    @Inject
    public Composite(List<Abstraction> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void execute() { 
        list.forEach(Abstraction::execute);
    }
}
```

How do I set it up so that the set of implementations to the abstraction gets injected properly into the Composite above? I will be having another object that takes the abstraction as a dependency and I want it to receive the `@Named` Composite above with the 2 Implementations below injected into the ctor.

```
public class Implementation1 implements Abstraction {
    public void execute() { }
}

public class Implementation2 implements Abstraction {
    public void execute() { }
}
```

Comment: Will it always be two? Just inject them separately by name.

Comment: @Pillar It my particular case, I can do that, but not sure how because I can't put the `Named` annotation on each implementation. sorry I'm new to java beans world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a bean for each of your implementations, your example will work out of the box. For example, annotate your implementations with `@Named` or `@Component` and mark them for scanning (component scan their package)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(StackOverflow.class);
        System.out.println(ctx.getBean(Composite.class).list);
    }
}

interface Abstraction {
    void execute();
}

@Named
class Composite implements Abstraction {
    List<Abstraction> list;

    @Inject
    public Composite(List<Abstraction> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void execute() {
        list.forEach(Abstraction::execute);
    }
}

@Named
class Implementation1 implements Abstraction {
    public void execute() {
    }
}

@Named
class Implementation2 implements Abstraction {
    public void execute() {
    }
}
```

The `Composite`'s list will contain both implementations.

Alternatively, since you only have two implementations, you could name their beans and inject them separately. For example

```
@Component("one")
class Implementation1 implements Abstraction {
    public void execute() {
    }
}

@Component("two")
class Implementation2 implements Abstraction {
    public void execute() {
    }
}
```

and inject them in the `Composite`

```
List<Abstraction> list = new ArrayList<>(2);

@Inject
public Composite(@Qualifier("one") Abstraction one, @Qualifier("two") Abstraction two) {
    list.add(one);
    list.add(two);
}
```

I suggest this solution just because the order of initialization of `Abstraction` beans might mess up your context initialization. For example if `Implementation1` somehow depended on the initialization of `Composite`, the context would complain. This is rare and you can control it in other ways. Still, being explicit about the beans might be clearer in this case.

Comment: You first scenario is applicable in my case, I do not care the order in which the list of abstractions is populated for my composite. But I see that when the composite bean is created it actually has the other 2 implementations in it just fine, but when another bean is attempted to be created that depends on `Abstraction` how will it know that it should inject the composite? I get an error in this case: `expected single matching bean but found 3: implementation2,composite,implementation1`

Comment: @JonErickson You'll need to qualify it with a name and use that name at the injection point. Alternatively, define a separate interface that's a subtype of `Abstraction` (like `CompositieAbstract`), have `Composite` implement it, and inject against that.

Comment: gotcha, I added a `Named("composite")` annotation to the composite and then added the `Qualifier("composite")` annotation to the constructor parameter on the other object. Thanks for your help